# Postgres: Inconsistent reported row numbers by failed Copy error

Tags: postgresql, copy

I have a file foo that I'd like to copy into a table.

```
\copy stage.from_csv FROM '/path/foo.dat' CSV;
```

If foo has an error like column mismatch or bad type, the return error is normal:

```
CONTEXT:  COPY from_csv, line 5, column report_year: "aa"
```

However, if the error is caused by an extraneous quotation mark, the reported line number is always one greater than the size of the file.

```
CONTEXT:  COPY from_csv, line 11: "02,2004,"05","123","09228","00","SUSX","PR",30,,..."
```

The source file has 10 lines, and I placed the error in line 5. If you examine the information in the CONTEXT message, it contains the line 5 data, so I know postgres can identify the row itself. However, it cannot identify the row by number. I have done this with a few different file lengths and the returned line number behavior is consistent.

Anyone know the cause and/or how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the error manifests only at the end of the file.

Look at this CSV file:

```
"google","growing",1,2
"google","growing",2,3
"google","falling","3,4
"google","growing",4,5
"yahoo","growing",1,2
```

There is a bug in the third line, an extra `"` has been added before the `3`.

Now to parse a CSV file, you first read until you hit the next line break.
But be careful, line breaks that are within double quotes don't count!
So all of the line breaks are part of a quoted string, and the line continues until the end of file.

Now that we have read our line, we can continue parsing it and notice that the number of quotes is unbalanced. Hence the error message:

```
ERROR:  unterminated CSV quoted field
CONTEXT:  COPY stock, line 6: ""google","falling","3,4
"google","growing",4,5
"yahoo","growing",1,2
"
```

In a nutshell: the error does not occur until we have reached the end of file.